# Welding Transformers?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, inductance

I was thinking of making a carry handle for two microwave oven transformers in series, and also so that they can share a common ground without having to split the ground wire. I thought about bolting an H type handle to the frame (The base of the transformer comes pre-drilled for mounting inside the microwave), but can I weld the handle to the transformer? I heard that it can cause eddy currents which may affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean welding directly to the transformer's laminations it's likely a bad idea.  Transformers are made of laminations of thin magnetic material to increase the resistance to the flow of eddy currents as you mentioned.  Welding would short a bunch of the laminations together and likely cause higher losses.  It might still work, but would not likely perform to its design specifications.

Comment: It won't cause large losses. Good manufacture of transformer comes already MIG welded, this reduces hum noise of laminations.

Comment: Probably not, but being welded during manufacture in a specific characterized way and having a handle welded on by someone with unknown sensitivity to the issues may be two very different things.

Comment: @JohnD Well, I'm not going to mess with the windings or anything. I don't want to throw the entire thing in the garbage can. Also, I wouldn't set the MIG welder on a high voltage.